# TF 10 Hz Polling Limit?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm publishing a transform at 100 Hz and when I poll TF I can only see changes at 10Hz. I can see that the messages exist at 100 Hz by running:

rostopic echo /tf

How can I see transforms at the rate I'm publishing?

Cheers,
Willy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160101/tf-10-hz-polling-limit?/) by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on 2014-05-03**:
You got it Tully. I was spanning across a slower transform. Thanks so much!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-05-03**:
I converted the comment to a question, and elaborated slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you polling? Are you spanning across multiple transforms which are published at a different rate? There's no limit on how fast you can poll tf until you run out of processor time.

If the other transform has not arrived and you're asking for the latest information it will jump ahead with the slowest transform published in the chain connecting the requested transforms. You can get much more accurate time readings by querying for a time history from the buffer into the past instead of recording the latest value as it comes in.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0